# Reverse a stack using another stack, runtime error

Tags: arrays, c, stack, reverse

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct stack
{
    int top;
    int size;
    int *arr;
} fk;
fk *stackcreater()
{
    fk *new = (fk *)malloc(sizeof(fk));
    new->size = 20;
    new->arr = (int *)malloc(new->size * sizeof(int));
    new->top = -1;
    return new;
}
int isfull(fk *s)
{
    return (s->top == s->size - 1);
}
int isempty(fk *s)
{
    return (s->top == -1);
}
void push(fk *s, int data)
{
    if (isfull(s))
    {
        printf("stack overflow");
    }
    else
    {
        s->top++;
        s->arr[s->top] = data;
    }
}
int pop(fk *s)
{
    if (isempty(s))
    {
        printf("stack underflow");
    }
    else
    {
        int val = s->arr[s->top];
        s->top--;
        return val;
    }
}
void display(fk *s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= s->top; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", s->arr[i]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    fk *s = stackcreater();
    fk *reverse = stackcreater();
    int n, val;
    do
    {
        printf("how many elements you want to insert: \t");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while (n > s->size);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        push(s, i);
    }
    display(s);
    printf("\n");
    while (!isempty(s))
    {
        val = pop(s);
        push(reverse, val);
    }
    display(reverse);

    free(s);
    free(reverse);
    free(s->arr);
    free(reverse->arr);
    return 0;
}
```

this code i wrote for reversing a stack as a newbie, this i think its working to some extent, as when i run it in vs code, its taking a minute to load and then asks for n, instead shouldn't it ask for it instantly after run, i thought maybe issue with vs code but no, the online compiler i used then, it showed runtime error, segmentation fault

Comment: `free(s->arr);` You are not allowed to access the memory where `s` points to after you freed that memory. Move that line before `free(s);`. Same for `reverse`. The result of this error is undefined behaviour which may result in the segmentation fault you observed.

Comment: Did you compiler show some warning about not returning a value from `pop` in some cases?

Comment: If I run your code with the fixed sequence of `free` calls, I get correct result without any error and I get asked for input immediately. I don't see anything wrong apart from the freeing.